# how to create datatype unique sqlsever?

Tags: sql-server-2008

i have two table.

```
table test1
{
id int identity(1,1),
name char(40) primary key
}

table test2
{
id int primary,
_test1 int
}
```

i want that _test1 was foreign key from Tbl test1(id). but it has error.how can i do `id` int test1 `unique`?

Answer (score 1):

Add a [unique constraint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191166.aspx) on `id` in `test1`

```
create table test1
(
  id int identity unique,
  name char(40) primary key
)

create table test2
(
  id int primary key,
  _test1 int references test1(id)
)
```